# sed match 3 lines patterns and delete 2

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I'm trying to match 3 lines that matches 3 different patterns, one after the other, and to delete ONLY the first and the last one with sed:

```
patternABC
patternDEF
patternGHI
```

I'm using something like this, which of course delete all the lines, but I need to leave patternDEF and delete ONLY patternABC and patternGHI.

```
sed -e '/patternABC/{N;/patternDEF/{N;/patternGHI/d}}'
```

Comment: so if line1, line2 and line3 match exactly you want to just keep line2? Better present a broader example together with the desired output, to make it more clear.

Comment: Yes exactly if I have line1, line2 and line3 I want to removed line1 and line3 and have as an output only line2 left

Comment: Are there 3 different patterns or 3 occurrences of a single pattern?

Comment: 3 different patterns as I named them differently, let's say then
<pre>
abc
def
ghi
</pre>
So I want to delete the line that match "abc" and "ghi" only if between them there is "def" , so techinically I want to leave "def"

Comment: Do not clarify the question in comments: just update it using the "edit" button. It is best for everybody: you get more attention and possible answerers get a more clear vision.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e '/patternABC/{
           N
           /\n.*patternDEF/{
              N
              /.*patternABC.*\(\n.*patternDEF.*\)\n.*patternGHI.*/ {
                 s//\1/
                 }
              }
           }' YourFile
```

- Assuming the 3 line are following and that you don't have something like line1+line1+line2+line3
- The `s//` is for the example and it can directly integregate the last level of pattern testing (so only 2 level of patternm matching + 1 substition is needed).
- `d` cannot be directly used because it delete the whole buffer content at once and the buffer is usualy the current line unless you add something to the current buffer like with the `N` action

  - pattern is now your concern about regex to use (`<pre> abc def ghi </pre>` is 1 line so this code could not work because it need 3 line)