# sed/awk/perl remove the first two lines of a 3 line pattern

Tags: perl, ubuntu, awk, sed

I have a huge text file. I need to replace all occurrences of this three line 
pattern:

```
|pattern|some data|
|giberish|,,
|pattern|some other data|
```

by the last line of the pattern:

```
|pattern|some other data|
```

**remove the first two lines of the pattern, keep only the last one**.

- The second line of the pattern ends with two commas and does not start with `|pattern|`
- The first line of the pattern line starts with `|pattern|` and does not end with two commas.
- The third line of the pattern line starts with `|pattern|` and does not end with two commas.

I tried this:

```
sed 'N;N;/^|pattern|.*\n.*,,\n|pattern|.*/I,+1 d' trial.txt
```

with no much luck

Edit: Here is a more substantial example

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cat > trial.txt <<EOL
|pattern|sdkssd|
|.x,mz|e,dsa|,,
|pattern|sdk;sd|
|xl'x|cxm;s|,,
|pattern|aslkaa|
|l'kk|3lke|,,
|x;;lkaa|c,c,s|
|-0-ses|3dsd|
|xk;xzz|'l3ld|
|0=9c09s|klkl32|
|d0-zox|m,3,a|
|x'.za|wkl;3|
|=-0poxz|3kls|
|x-]0';a|sd;ks|
|wsd|756|
|sdw|;lksd|
|pattern|askjkas|
|xp]o]xa|lk3j2|,,
|]-p[z|lks|
EOL
```

and it should become:

```
|pattern|aslkaa|
|l'kk|3lke|,,
|x;;lkaa|c,c,s|
|-0-ses|3dsd|
|xk;xzz|'l3ld|
|0=9c09s|klkl32|
|d0-zox|m,3,a|
|x'.za|wkl;3|
|=-0poxz|3kls|
|x-]0';a|sd;ks|
|wsd|756|
|sdw|;lksd|
|pattern|askjkas|
|xp]o]xa|lk3j2|,,
|]-p[z|lks|
```

---

@zdim:

the first three lines of the file:

```
|pattern|sdkssd|
|.x,mz|e,dsa|,,
|pattern|sdk;sd|
```

satisfy the pattern. So they are replaced by

```
|pattern|sdk;sd|
```

so the top of the file now becomes:

```
|pattern|sdk;sd|
|xl'x|cxm;s|,,
|pattern|aslkaa|
|l'kk|3lke|,,
...
```

the first three lines of which are:

```
|pattern|sdk;sd|
|xl'x|cxm;s|,,
|pattern|aslkaa|
```

which satisfy the pattern, so they are replaced by:

```
|pattern|aslkaa|
```

so the top of the file now is:

```
|pattern|aslkaa|
|l'kk|3lke|,,
|x;;lkaa|c,c,s|
|-0-ses|3dsd|
....
```

---

@JosephQuinsey:

consider this file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cat > trial.txt <<EOL
|pattern|blabla|
|||4|||-0.97|0|1429037262.8271||20160229||1025||1000.0|0.01|,,
|pattern|blable|
|||5|||-1.27|0|1429037262.854||20160229||1025||1000.0|0.01|,,
|pattern|blasbla|
|||493|||-0.22|5|1429037262.8676||20170228||1025||1000.0|0.01|,,
|||11|||-0.22|5|1429037262.8676||20170228||1025||1000.0|0.01|,|T|347||1429043438.1962|-0.22|5|0||-0.22|1429043438.1962|,|Q|346||1429043437.713|-0.24|26|-0.22|5|||1429043437.713|
|pattern|jksds|
|||232|||-5.66|0|1429037262.817||20150415||1025||1000.0|0.01|,,
|pattern|bdjkds|
|||123q|||-7.15|0|1429037262.8271||20150415||1025||1000.0|0.01|,,
|pattern|blabla|
|||239ps|||-1.38|79086|1429037262.8773||20150415||1025||1000.0|0.01|,,
|||-92opa|||-1.38|79086|1429037262.8773||20150415||1025||1000.0|0.01|,|T|1||1428969600.5019|-0.99|1|11||||,
|||kj2w|||-1.38|79086|1429037262.8773||20150415||1025||1000.0|0.01|,|T|2||1428969600.5019|-1|1|11||||,
|||0293|||-1.38|79086|1429037262.8773||20150415||1025||1000.0|0.01|,|T|3||1428969600.5019|-1.01|1|11||||,
|||2;;w32|||-1.38|79086|1429037262.8773||20150415||1025||1000.0|0.01|,|T|4||1428969600.5019|-1.11|1|11||||,
EOL
```

Comment: so do you mean replace line 3 with `|pattern|still some other different data` OR can you just delete lines 1 & 2? Please update your Q if appropriate. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter: the sentence 'remove the first two lines of the pattern' was in the original question. I have accentuated it. !You only need to delete line 1 & 2!. Why Good luck? Is this a complicated thing to do?

Comment: 'remove the first two lines of the pattern' seems less ambiguous. I sign all my comments Good luck. Even this one, Good luck ;-)!

Comment: Why the downvotes?!

Comment: The shown sample starts with a three-line pattern, the last one being `|pattern|sdk;sd|`. So I'd expect that in the output, but it's not? Now, that line itself starts another pattern, which ends with what you actually show in the desired output.  What gives?

Comment: @zdim: see explication in edit (I need multi-line).

Comment: Ah, so if they happen to be chained then the whole thing goes.  Alright :)

Comment: @zdim: it feels a little bit like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29558738/189035) question, except my case is more constrained (my patterns are strictly at the  beginning/end of lines). But I don't understand advanced awk good enough to make sense of the answer there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple take on it, using a buffer to collect and manage the pattern-lines

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $file = shift or die "Usage: $0 file\n";

open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";

my @buf;

while (<$fh>) { 
    chomp;
    if (/^\|pattern\|/ and not /,,$/) { 
        @buf = $_;     # start the buffer (first line) or overwrite (third)
    }   
    elsif (/,,$/ and not /^\|pattern\|/) { 
        if  (@buf) { push @buf, $_ }  # add to buffer with first line in it
        else       { say }            # not part of 3-line-pattern; print
    }   
    else { 
        say for @buf;  # time to print out buffer
        @buf = ();     # ... empty it ...
        say            # and print the current line
    }   
}
```

This prints the expected output.

Explanation.

- Pattern-lines go in a buffer, and when we get the "third line" the first two need be removed. Then "assign" to the array whenever we see `^|pattern|` -- either to start the buffer if it's the first line or to re-initialize the array (removing what's in it) if it's the third line
- A line ending with `,,` is added to the buffer, if there is a line there already. Nothing prohibits lines ending with `,,` just so -- they may be outside of a pattern; in that case just print it
- So each `|pattern|` line sets the buffer straight -- either starts it or resets it.  Thus once we run into a line with neither `^|pattern|` nor `,,$` we can print out our buffer, and that line

Please test more comprehensively, what i still didn't get to do.

---

In order to run this either in a pipeline or on a file use the ["magical" `<>`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I%2fO-Operators) filehandle.  So it becomes

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my @buf;

while (<>) {  # reads lines from files given on command line, or from STDIN
    ...
}
```

Now you can run it either as `data | script.pl` or as `script.pl datafile`. (Make the script executable for this, or use as `perl script.pl`.)

The script's output goes to `STDOUT` which can be piped into other programs or redirected to a file.

Comment: sorry, but what language is this? How do you use it in the bash prompt (suppose the file is named trial.txt)

Comment: @user189035 Oh ... it's a Perl program. You run it as `scriptname.pl datafile`, where the shown program goes in the `scriptname.pl` file (call it any name of course), which is made executable.  (Or you can run it as `perl scriptname.pl datafile`) This _can_ be massaged into a "one-liner" but that'd be too much complexity and mess

Comment: can this be changed to be included in a pipe chain: `... | perl perlscript.pl | ... > trial2.txt`?

Comment: @user189035 Edited regex, to disallow `|pattern|` to end with `,,` and to disallow `,,$` to start with `|pattern|`.  Perhaps a nitpick but it's your requirement.

Comment: @user189035 "_included in a pipe chain_" -- sure ... what comes down the pipe to it?  The data, line by line ...?

Comment: @user189035 Updated, see the added part

Comment: I confirm it works perfectly and is 3 times faster than a tac | awk | tac based solution. Allow me to check the other answers out of respect.

Answer (score 1):

***Updated answer:*** The following **sed** solution should work:

```
  sed '/\n/!N;/\n.*\n/!N;/^|pattern|.*\n.*,,\n|pattern|/!{P;D;};s/[^\n]*\n//;D;'
```

Explanation:

- `/\n/!N` if the P-space has only one line, read the next
- `/\n.*\n/!N` if the P-space has only two lines, read in a third
- `/^|pattern|.*\n.*,,\n|pattern|/` test if the first and third lines start with |pattern|, and the middle line ends with two commas
- `!{P;D;}` if the match *fails*, then print the first line and start over
- `s/[^\n]*\n//;D;` otherwise, when the match *succeeds*, delete the first two lines, and start over.

Comment: also, shouldn't the second `|pattern|` be followed by `.*` (just guess, i'm not a sed god or anything). Something else: the third `|pattern|`: it should leave the third line of the pattern in place (*not* ```|pattern|```. I have edited the example to make this more clear)

Comment: I gave an example in the edit where the code does not seem to give the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks. Just to confirm that this code *is* giving the desired result. Thank you again. For info, it takes about 3 times as much time on my system to run (on a 1GB file) as @zdim's solution.

Comment: @user189035: Interesting about the speed! Anyway, it is good to have two independent solutions, so you can check one against the other.

Answer (score 1):

It may depend on how your file is huge but if it is smaller than the allowed memory size, how about:

```
perl -0777 -pe '
    1 while s/^\|pattern\|.+?\|\n(?<!\|pattern\|).+?,,\n(\|pattern\|.+?\|)$/\1/m;
' trial.txt
```

Output:

```
|pattern|aslkaa|
|l'kk|3lke|,,
|x;;lkaa|c,c,s|
|-0-ses|3dsd|
|xk;xzz|'l3ld|
|0=9c09s|klkl32|
|d0-zox|m,3,a|
|x'.za|wkl;3|
|=-0poxz|3kls|
|x-]0';a|sd;ks|
|wsd|756|
|sdw|;lksd|
|pattern|askjkas|
|xp]o]xa|lk3j2|,,
|]-p[z|lks|
```

Comment: in the section `(?<!pattern)`, should this be `(?<!\|pattern\|)`?

Comment: @user189035 thank you for pointing out. It will be more appropriate. I've modified my answer accordingly.

Comment: I confirm the answer works. Tho it was not specific in the question, this will be operating on huge files so that I cannot guarantee they would fit in memory.

Answer (score 1):

An awk solution:

```
awk -v pa=pattern '
    $0 ~ pa {
        do {
            hold=$0;
            getline;
            hold=hold "\n" $0;
            getline;
        } while(match($0, pa));
        print hold
    }
    1' trial.txt
```

The idea is to buffer the line that matched the pattern, then the line after. If the next line also matches the pattern, loop, this time buffer the most recent matching line and and the one following it. This has the effect of removing the lines that need to be replaced.

When the loop stops, the first line the buffer contains is either the line to replace the removed lines or simply a first pattern match that is not to be removed. Either way the contents of the buffer get printed.

The final `1` statement is needed to print the line that ended the while loop and all other lines that aren't the first or second after one matching the pattern.

Comment: Thank you: I'm a bit biased because I find awk a bit more readable, so your solution is my personal favorite;) I tried to do that in awk and for the life of me could not figure this out. It's (by a small amount) faster than @zdim's solution on a 1GB file.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;N;s/[^\n]*/&/3;Ta;/^|pattern|.*\n.*,,\n|pattern|/{/,,\n.*\n\|,,$/!{s/.*\n//;ba}};P;D' file
```

Populate the pattern space with the next three lines of the file. If the first pattern matches the current three lines and neither the first or the third line ends with `,,`, then delete the first two lines and repeat. Otherwise print and delete the first line of the three line window and repeat.

Comment: Thank you. I confirm it passes my test data set. On my machine, on the  1GB file  I use for tests, it seems it is much slower than the awk solution of @Graeme (the fastest solution so far). Could it be that the regex search is slower than ```match()``` he uses? I have near 0 knowledge of these things but would have liked to know.